# Node.js doesn't display the contents of an HTML file

Tags: html, node.js

My code is this:

```
var http = require('http'),
url = require('url'),
fs = require('fs');

var handleRequest = function(request, response) {
console.log("Request received: " + request.url);
var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;

switch(path){
    case '/':
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        response.write("<h1>Hello there!</h1>");
        break;

    case '/socket.html':
        console.log(__dirname + path);
        fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error, data){
                console.log(data);
                if (error){
                    response.writeHead(404);
                    response.write("This page doesn't exist");
                }
                else{
                    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
                    response.write(data, "utf8");
                }
            });
        break;

    default:
        response.writeHead(404);
        response.write("This page doesn't exist");
        break;
}
response.end();
};

var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);

server.listen(3000, "localhost", function() {
    console.log("Listening to port 3000...")
});
```

The HTML file is in the same directory as this one. All it contains is a simple paragraph. The page loads but it is blank. When I console.log(data) it displays something like Buffer 3c 21 44.... etc. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're ending the response immediately after starting your asynchronous, non-blocking `readFile()` task. Try this:

```
switch(path) {
  case '/':
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    response.write("<h1>Hello there!</h1>");
    break;

  case '/socket.html':
    fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error, data) {
      if (error) {
        response.writeHead(404);
        response.write("This page doesn't exist");
      } else {
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        response.write(data);
      }
      response.end();
    });
    return;

  default:
    response.writeHead(404);
    response.write("This page doesn't exist");
    break;
}

response.end();
```

Also, you might look into using streams to pipe files from disk to the response to avoid buffering the entire file in memory first.